# Laravel permission denied ( Database )

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello how can i grant permission of laravel for this error ( Production server ):

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied (SQL: select * from `users` where `name` = test and 
`pin_code` = "code here"
```

I have already grant 777 permission for : `storage/framework/sessions`, `storage/` and `bootstrap/cache`.

I Don't know this problem.

I have try to fix this problem with a permission `ALL PRIVILEGES` of my database.

Migration are ok.

Comment: The user that you use in your laravel is the same that you granted the permissions? This error is on SQL, so with the information provided in error we can assume that is an SQL permission error. Try to check again the user permission on your database and check if is the same user that you're trying to do the select

Comment: good evening i have create 1 more user than root and is the same result and if i connect the user with the another password, than the specified user password in database i have the same error

Comment: Did you configure your database user and password in your `.env` file?

Comment: Hello yes i did it

Comment: One thing that you can do is check from your connection the user that are referenced, check with `DB::connect(<nameofyourdb>)::getConfig('username');` to check if the user is the same that you're granting permissions.

Comment: ok thank you i will try your fix soon